# Is there a fix for number counter bug using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

- I made products quantity counter for e-commerce that should increase and decrease the quantity by 1 and it works only if the elements exist in dom without appending from javascript
- but when I  click on the get button to append from javascript the last appended element only increases or decreases by one.

here is the code:

```js
class Cart {

  static global() {
    Cart.getBtn = document.getElementById('get');
    Cart.main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
    Cart.min = 1;
  }

  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  static insertEl() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1">
            <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
        </div>
        `;
    Cart.main.appendChild(div);
  }

  static plusFunc() {
    // plus btn
    let plus = document.querySelectorAll('.plus');
    plus.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let input = e.target.previousElementSibling;
        let max = Number(input.getAttribute('max'));
        let num1 = new Cart(Number(input.value));

        if (num1.num >= Cart.min) {
          num1.num += 1;
        }
        if (num1.num >= max) {
          num1.num = max;
        }

        input.value = num1.num;

      });
    });
  }

  static minusFunc() {
    // minus btn
    let minus = document.querySelectorAll('.minus');
    minus.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let input = e.target.nextElementSibling;
        let max = Number(input.getAttribute('max'));
        let num1 = new Cart(Number(input.value));

        if (num1.num <= max) {
          num1.num -= 1;
        }
        if (num1.num <= Cart.min) {
          num1.num = Cart.min;
        }

        input.value = num1.num;

      });
    });
  }

}
Cart.global();

// events
Cart.getBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Cart.insertEl();
  Cart.plusFunc();
  Cart.minusFunc();
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="get">get</button>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a new plus and a new minus listener to each element whenever a new element is appended. Have `plusFunc` and `minusFunc` only add to the newly created element instead:

```js
class Cart {

  static global() {
    Cart.getBtn = document.getElementById('get');
    Cart.main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
    Cart.min = 1;
  }

  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  static insertEl() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1">
            <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
        </div>
        `;
    Cart.main.appendChild(div);
    return div;
  }

  static plusFunc(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let input = e.target.previousElementSibling;
      let max = Number(input.getAttribute('max'));
      let num1 = new Cart(Number(input.value));

      if (num1.num >= Cart.min) {
        num1.num += 1;
      }
      if (num1.num >= max) {
        num1.num = max;
      }

      input.value = num1.num;

    });
  }

  static minusFunc(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let input = e.target.nextElementSibling;
      let max = Number(input.getAttribute('max'));
      let num1 = new Cart(Number(input.value));

      if (num1.num <= max) {
        num1.num -= 1;
      }
      if (num1.num <= Cart.min) {
        num1.num = Cart.min;
      }

      input.value = num1.num;

    });
  }

}
Cart.global();

// events
Cart.getBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const div = Cart.insertEl();
  const [minus, plus] = div.querySelectorAll('button');
  Cart.plusFunc(plus);
  Cart.minusFunc(minus);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="get">get</button>
<main></main>
```

But this quite a weird setup - why have a class that basically has nothing but static methods? Consider a plain object instead:

```js
const Cart = {
  getBtn: document.getElementById('get'),
  main: document.querySelector('main'),
  min: 1,
  max: 20,
  insertEl() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
      <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1">
      <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
    `;
    this.main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
    this.main.appendChild(div);
    return div;
  }
}
Cart.getBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const div = Cart.insertEl();
  const [minus, input, plus] = div.children;
  minus.addEventListener('click', () => input.value = Math.max(Cart.min, input.value - 1));
  plus.addEventListener('click', () => input.value = Math.min(Cart.max, Number(input.value) + 1));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="get">get</button>
<main></main>
```

Comment: you saved my life thank you so much, I am using this setup because I wanna get used to oop that's all